# The best way to deal with 404 errors in MVC?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, error-handling, dispatcher

So I wrote my PHP MVC framework, and have Dispatcher class that can instantiate appropriate Controller class and call defined method passing arguments.

Now inside Dispatcher I check if this Controller exists and if method exists, what should I do if controller or method does not exist?

At the moment I just return HTTP Object that prints 404 - Page not found.
But there is no way for me to customize this message from inside application, and I want to provide users a way to customize 404 messages without editing dispatcher.

Is a good way to go to always have Error controller that would get instantiated when there is a error, and that would load lets say Error404.html view file?
So users would be able to customize this view file to fit their application design.

Is there any other way to achive this? And what would be the best way to return error from dispatcher, and let "users" or developers that are working on that MVC to easily customize 404 and other messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose you have an error controller that takes in an error code (number or string) as an argument. This allows you to gracefully handle various kinds of errors and be able to provide a stack trace if necessary. You can even utilize this work for 500 errors.

My answer comes with the assumption that a controller can return various actions and each action can have it's own template.

Symfony also seems to handle errors in a similar fashion. They have a separate module and action for each error.

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getController()->forward(sfConfig::get('sf_error_404_m‌​odule'), sfConfig::get('sf_error_404_action'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly how MVC is working now.
Do you know how to detect HTTP 500 error with PHP? How would Dispatcher be aware that its a 500 error since if 500 happens application wouldn't be started at all?

Comment: Not 100% sure on that one. You can look into register_shutdown_function in php. You can also look into ErrorDocument with .htaccess and route all of your errors (or just 500) to your :controller/:action.

Comment: Yes , and you used it as an example, which would mean that you think it is appropriate. But it isn't.

Comment: It absolutely is appropriate to demonstrate that other major MVC frameworks use the same methodology of forwarding you to a specific controller and action if an error is found.

Answer (score 2):

Since i do not know your API, I am going to guess. Lets assume that you have a bootstrap stage in your application, when the dispatcher is actually used. Something like:

`$dispatcher->dispatch( $request );`

Then for handling request, that try to access non-existent controllers or methods within those controllers, you can do something like this:

```
try
{
    $dispatcher->dispatch( $request );
}
catch ( ClassNotFoundException $e )
{
    $dispatcher->dispatch( new Request('/error/404/controller'));
}
catch ( MethodNotFoundException $e )
{
    $dispatcher->dispatch( new Request('/error/404/method'));
}
```

The `ClassNotFoundException` can be thrown by your classloader, while dispatcher itself would always be responsible for throwing the `MethodNotFoundException`.

You can check, whether controller has a particular method,  with [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php), before executing it in your dispatcher.

> <sub>**P.S.** in my humble opinion, the *Dispatcher* conept is better suited for event driven architectures and not for MVC-inspired patterns in web applications.</sub>

Comment: I'm pretty sure this method would trigger if any classes or methods are not found in his entire execution chain. That would produce 404 errors even when there is just a bug in the code.

Comment: What execution chain? Do you have some magical powers to read his source? Also, notice the phrase "can be thrown", which means, that you could also throw it specifically from the *Dispatcher*.

Comment: You're an insufferable person teresko. And because of that I'm stepping back from this question. Best of luck Limeni.